# code work on jsfiddle but not on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, credit-card

Hey so recently i found some code online while looking for a method that can recognize the type of credit card as the numbers are being typed, i tried out the code on jsfiddle.net and it seemed to work fine, untill i decided to copy and paste the code into a blank .php file, the code will apear, i get no errors but it just wont do what its supposed to do. am i typing the code in the wrong places or something?

here is a link to original JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/9whmL9u0/

and here is my .php file:

```js
function detectCardType(number) {
    var re = {
        electron: /^(4026|417500|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917)\d+$/,
        maestro: /^(5018|5020|5038|5612|5893|6304|6759|6761|6762|6763|0604|6390)\d+$/,
        dankort: /^(5019)\d+$/,
        interpayment: /^(636)\d+$/,
        unionpay: /^(62|88)\d+$/,
        visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/,
        mastercard: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
        amex: /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,
        diners: /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$/,
        discover: /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/,
        jcb: /^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}$/
    };
    if (re.electron.test(number)) {
        return 'ELECTRON';
    } else if (re.maestro.test(number)) {
        return 'MAESTRO';
    } else if (re.dankort.test(number)) {
        return 'DANKORT';
    } else if (re.interpayment.test(number)) {
        return 'INTERPAYMENT';
    } else if (re.unionpay.test(number)) {
        return 'UNIONPAY';
    } else if (re.visa.test(number)) {
        return 'VISA';
    } else if (re.mastercard.test(number)) {
        return 'MASTERCARD';
    } else if (re.amex.test(number)) {
        return 'AMEX';
    } else if (re.diners.test(number)) {
        return 'DINERS';
    } else if (re.discover.test(number)) {
        return 'DISCOVER';
    } else if (re.jcb.test(number)) {
        return 'JCB';
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}

$(function(){

    $(".ckthis").keyup(function(){
        var thisNum = $(this).val();
        console.log(thisNum);
        $(".showThis").html(detectCardType(thisNum));
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ckthis">
<div class="showThis"></div>  
<br><br> SAMPLE TEST NUMBERS
<br><br> VISA:4539435089757850<br><br>
```

Comment: You need a server to run php file. Do you run on localhost? P.S. In your file i don't see php code....

Comment: where in your code are you loading jQuery?

Comment: yes i do, it runs but i dont think the js is running. it doesnt say visa or anything even though i copied it exactly and typed the same thing in the input

Comment: Why do you need to save it as a .php file when there is no php? Saving it as .html and running JS scripts should work just fine. And also you need to load JQuery library.

Comment: so, what is the address of this file in your browser ... is it `http://...` or `https://...` or is it `file:///...`

Comment: Your code woks fine as long as you load the jQuery library: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/Lw1hpq7y/2/

Comment: @JaromandaX the url is: https://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~s3656661/wp/a2/checkout2.php , oh and i cant believe i forgot to load jQuery.... im so dumb. Thanks for spotting it out

Comment: @Turnip yeh someone else also spotted that, cant beleive i missed it. Thanks a lot

Comment: oddly, you said there were no errors - yet `$` would be undefined, so there should have been errors in the browser developer tools console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see you've included your JQuery library.

Put this somewhere in your code *(e.g at the bottom, above your `<script>` tags)*

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or you can [download](https://jquery.com/download/) the whole library locally to your computer and refer to it that way instead.